# Visual Studio Code: Disable quote wrapping text selection

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I want to change from double quotes to single quotes, I'm used to selecting the double quote, and then type a single quote. I'm intending to use the overwrite feature, but instead, I'm getting the 'wrap with quote' feature.

For example:

```
"id"
```

Would result in:

```
'"'id"
```

I always turn this auto surround with wrapping off, but I was unable to find a setting for this in the settings file...

Is there a way to turn this off?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

It is possible!

In settings.json which you can open via File>Preferences>UserSettings

**UPDATE 2023**

There are two settings

```
"editor.autoSurround": "never",
```

Possible values:

- "never"
- "languageDefined" - This is vsCode's default
- "brackets" - meaning it automatically adds brackets, but not quotes
- "quotes" - meaning it automatically adds quotes but not brackets

```
"editor.autoClosingQuotes": "never",
```

Possible values:

- "never"
- "languageDefined" - This is vsCode's default
- "beforeWhitespace"
- "always"

---

*PS: In old ancient versions of vsCode, there was less granularity and a single setting would control quotes, braces and brackets. `"editor.autoClosingBrackets" : "never"`*

Comment: Thanks! Quite annoying that you can't control them individually though.

Comment: There is a "languageDefined" setting there, I guess it allows to configure it for each language

Comment: This is no longer a correct answer. See `editor.autoSurround` as pointed out in the other answer.

Comment: Do you realize `autoClosingBrackets` is not obsolete and it has a completely different function with `autoSurround`. Please edit your answer as it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't have a `UserSettings` alternative under `File>Preferences`, but I have a `Settings` alternatives, which has those specific settings and seems to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 37):

I found this question via Google and the selected answer didn't work for me. I'm using VSCode version 1.27.2, and for me the I had to disable the **Auto Surround** option.

```
"editor.autoSurround": "never"
```

Comment: Thank you!  This should be the selected answer!

Answer (score 13):

Using VSCode version: 1.36.0

You can use: `"editor.autoClosingQuotes": "never"`

or

[image]

[image]

Comment: Fwiw, there is a similar UI for _Auto Surround_, which I think is what this question is looking for.